# Selenium - WebDriver - Java: Why am I getting empty strings from my elements?

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

I have a webpage where some elements get set on page load.  I then need to read some of these elements using Selenium.  The problem is that when I read them, all I get is an empty string.

This is a partial image of my website:
[image: partial image of website]

I'm trying to obtain the Number field.
Here is what the DOM looks like for this element:

```
<input style="; ; " class="form-control disabled " id="sys_readonly.u_po_coordination.number" value="POI1356285" ng-non-bindable="" readonly="readonly" aria-label="Number">
```

Here is my JAVA code to get that value:

```
String num = driver.findElement(By.id("sys_readonly.u_po_coordination.number")).getText();
```

I've tried using XPath as well.  I've also tried getting other elements as well.
The result is ALWAYS the same: a blank string...

What am I missing?  The elements exist because I can set various elements, but reading ones that should be set are always blank.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
driver.findElement(By.id("sys_readonly.u_po_coordination.number")).getAttribute("value");
```

Found this website which was pretty useful:
https://www.lambdatest.com/blog/how-to-get-text-of-an-element-in-selenium/

Answer (score 0):

Instead of getText() can you try getValue()?